# How to design correctly a web app in sails.js?

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I build a web app using sails.js and I have few questions about the design of the app:

1. Should I create controllers for each page, component, or model? I saw in the documentation and at some tutorials that they create controllers for each model. That looks nice but if I have a complex page/component and I want to create view with multi models (and data) it doesn't help me.
2. Where should I put the business logic part of a component or feature? I read about Serivce but I'm not sure that this is the right place.

To sum up, I saw that in sails the code is arranged like the models (you have model, controller and view for each model) but what if I want to arrange it by features or components or pages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should have Controller for each Model (but if you don't need specific controller and it would be empty you don't need to create it). It's just a good practice to have a Controller for each Model.

If you use some part of code in many places and it is not connected with one specified Model it should be **Service** (like sending emails, notifications, logging, images processing). Read about [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Controller should be as simple as possible. It should contain call of Model and Service and callback with rendering output. All business logic should be in Models.

I created some additional 'helper' Models for more complex Models like Users or so to make Classes bit shorter.

To sum up. Core of your application is Model. It's not only responsible for database layer, bur also business layer of your app. Later there is Controller. It gets data from Model and it passes it to Views which is responsible for presentation of data taken from Model.

Answer (score -1):

## Answer to First

Sails is for REST API it has nothing to do with view.

you just need to know what MVC is and what REST is....

In one Controller you can invoke multiple models or one model can be invoked in multiple controllers.

In one page you can fetch data from two different API's which may be from different controller or Even they can be of different server.
for Example:

> 1. In the page you are getting data directly from ellasticsearchAPI(say esAPI1)
> 2. You are getting data from sails API(sAPI1).
> 3. You are getting data from other sails API(sAPI2).

## Answer to Second

For neatness you should try to keep controller as clean as possible. So for the same sailsJS provide you services. Where you can write Common functionalities which are to be used in multiple controllers.

**See the codes for example**

## Codes

here is the controller:

```
//TestController
module.exports = {
    action1:function(req,res){
        Model1.find().exec(function(err,data1){
            if(err)
                return res.negotiate(err);
            res.ok(data1);
        });
    },
    action2:function(req,res){
        Model2.find().exec(function(err,data1){
            if(err)
                return res.negotiate(err);
            res.ok(data2);
        });
    },
    action3:function(req,res){
        var hash=SomeService.getMeHashCode(req.query.text)
        res.ok({hashedData:hash});
    }
};
```

And this is service.

```
//SomeService.js
module.exports = {
    getMeHashCode:function(strinToBeHashed){
        var hash=doSomeThingToHash(strinToBeHashed);
        return hash;
    }
};
```

Comment: That's simply wrong. Sails is often used for REST API but it also [supports views](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/views). A new Sails app has some default views like 404. Of course if you ask for a json response in your request, sails wan't send you html. There is also a [build process using Grunt](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/gruntfile-js) for asset management.

Comment: i didn't say if sails does not support view.
my answer was based on the question.Read answer carefull then judge!